# How to get time difference in months in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here is how my current dataset is formatted:

```
USER    START_DATE    END_DATE    NB_MONTHS
--------------------------------------------
111     2020-01-01    2021-02-01  13
222     2020-05-17    2020-09-28  16
333     2020-02-01    2020-03-01  0
```

Each of my users currently have a start date and an end date for an action they've completed.
I wish to find the time duration of their action in MONTHS (as defined by the NB_MONTHS_ flag).

Here is my current query to get this NB_MONTHS flag:

```
SELECT 
    USERS,
    FLOOR((END_DATE)-(START_DATE))/30.00 as NB_MONTHS
FROM 
    TABLE1;
```

I am currently rounding down this flag as that is what makes most sense for my analysis.

Here is where I get an issue:

My user 333 who has technically taking 1 month to complete the action (duration of February) is currently beeing flagged as "0 months" because February has 28 days (which doesnt work with my query).

Anyone know how I can avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `datediff()` do what you want?

```
SELECT USERS,
       DATEDIFF(MONTH, START_DATE, END_DATE) as NB_MONTHS
FROM TABLE1;
```

Comment: Yes it works! I however have a caveat: Some of my users who do not have an end_date (who have not completed the action) have an end_date of '2999-12-31'. Its a default end_date. What I would like to do is, for those users, take CURRENT_DATE instead of the '2999-12-31'. Where should I put my CASE WHEN statement to apply this condition? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You probably want `datediff(month, start_date, least(end_date, current_date))` . . . but you might have valid future end dates that are not "infinite".  In that case, you would want a `case` expression.